# Shorten files' name using regular expressions

Tags: windows, regex, rename, batch-rename, jdownloader

I'm downloading some files using JDownloader, however the file name of the files that captured are too long and they can't be downloaded. 
I hope to shorten their name to not more than 40 characters using the rename feature with regular expressions.

Please see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP4yd.jpg)

I use this in

search for: (.*)
Search by: {,40}

but obviously doesn't work. What should I use? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: this idea may help.. you maybe can't find x char and just use those. But you can find the whole thing and capture just x char and replace with that. e.g. `C:\>echo alli| sed -r "s/(.{2}).*/\1/g"`   returns `al` of `alli` i.e. the first 2 characters. So that'd be a search replace that'd do it using regex, you just need the right program now.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but sorry maybe I confused you.
I just need the regex for shorten the files' name before I hit download. 
So the download will be in a shorter format.

Comment: looking at your screenshot, your find/replace  is completely wrong and makes no sense.  And you shouldn't have described it as as "search for" and "search by"

Comment: what should i use instead?

Comment: what terms should you use instead? The same ones that every program uses. e.g. in notepad if you do ctrl-h you see the find and replace window. You can call it "find and replace"..  Notepad says "find what"  and "replace with".  or you could say the "find" box and the "replace". box

Comment: and it seems that the downloading is irrelevant. You have files on your computer and you want to cut their filenames. So the output you could look for is a file that says   `move longfilenameblahabcdefghij.xyz longfilenameblahabcd`  the file could have started with the first line saying `longfilenameblahabcdefghij.xyz` and each subsequent line also haveing one line per filename. you then turn that file of long filenames, into a bunch of move commands (move can be used to rename files)  You can use command line tools to turn that list of long filenames into a file of move statements.

Comment: Sorry it should be "Search for" and "Replace by" It was typo.

Comment: use notepad is irrelevant, the download list on the jdownloader, I can rename the list within jdownloader. 
So here's what I need: Search for (regex for search all file) Replace by (regex to shorten the name of the files)

Comment: a typo means a spelling error.. not an entire word wrong.. Notepad was relevant for telling you what words to use for "search" and "replace".  Not for anything else. Also, not many people use jdownloader.   And if you want a regex you could try to find the regex in notepad++ and then apply that regex in jdownloader.

Comment: so how about http://i.imgur.com/VgFYmvf.png